# Logentries how to log /dev/stdout

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, agent, logentries

I'm using Logentries and Kubernetes and I've tried the Logentries [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/logentries/docker-logentries) which works well but all logs get sent to the same log. I need a way to send logs from different containers to different logs and the logs should be created in Logentries if they do not exist (like what is possible with the [Logentries agent](https://github.com/rapid7/le)).

As far as I can tell there is no way to do this, or is there?

That led me to try to use the agent on my application container, but here I have a different problem. The agent can't seem to track logs that are sent to `/dev/stdout`, my Nginx log file is configured like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Feb  6 08:12 access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

And I tried both of these in the `/etc/le/config` file but neither works:

```
[access_log]
path = /var/log/nginx/access.log
destination = logname/var/log/nginx/access.log

[stdout]
path = /dev/stdout
destination = logname/dev/stdout
```

Is there a way I can get the agent to track these logs correctly?